# How to check if the user has called a number within the last week?

Tags: java, android

I want to be able to check if the user has called a number within the last week and if they haven't display a Toast.

So far, I've created a function that gets the users Call logs. However, im not sure how I would check whether they have called someone within a period of time such as a week?

This is my code:

```
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    Cursor managedCursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    sb.append("Call Log :");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callType = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String dir = null;
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(callType);
        switch (dircode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                dir = "OUTGOING";
                break;

            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                dir = "INCOMING";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                dir = "MISSED";
                break;
        }

        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNumber +
                " \nCall Type:--- " + dir +
                " \nCall Date:--- " + callDayTime +
                " \nCall duration in sec :--- " +
                callDuration);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");

    }
```

Just wondering what the best way to do this is?

Thanks!

Comment: You already have Calling date, Whats the issue in finding the called numbers of last week? Use `Calender`or `Date` class for comparison

Comment: Im not sure what the structure would look like?

Comment: You are already going through all the calls, so just put conditionals. I would first check the date (if it is within the desired days continue processing, else go to the next one), then I would check the phoneNumber and if it is the one you are looking for I would check the calltype

Comment: @Ivan Thanks for your help! I think I understand and ill give it a try.

Comment: Hi @Ivan, anychance you could post an answer still stuck as to how you would do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the approximation of my comment. It's pseudo-code, but just few things to change to make it work.
Hope this helps.

```
while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String callDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDayTime = new Date(Long.valueOf(callDate));
        if (<compare callDayTime with a "Date" of one week ago> ){
            String phNumber = managedCursor.getString(number);
            if (<phNumber is equal to the desired Phone>) {
                if(Integer.parseInt(callType) == CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE){
                    // User called the phone number last week
                }
            }
        }       
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks alot that worked brilliantly! Really appreciate it.